# How to Monitor If my current Location is getting close to a preset Location

Tags: windows-phone-7

say, I have setUp a location I wanted to go for example Time Square ( LatLon :40.760586,-73.984852) in my WP App. Suppose, I want to travel in a taxi to go to Time Square and with my app turn on. How do I keep tracking my current GPS is getting closer to that place?? How to determine  I am withing the range?? The below code is for current GPS.

```
 GeoCoordinateWatcher tracker;

 void tracker_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs e)
 {


    textLatitude.Text = e.Position.Location.Latitude.ToString("0.000");
    textLongitude.Text = e.Position.Location.Longitude.ToString("0.000");

}
```

Thank in advance. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GeoCoordinate class already has [GetDistanceTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.aspx) method

It can be used as follows:

```
GeoCoordinate start = new GeoCoordinate(startLatitude, startLongitude);
GeoCoordinate end = new GeoCoordinate(endLatitude, endLongitude);  
double distance = start.GetDistanceTo(end);
```

You can set this to be calculated every time the GeoCoordinateWatcher class fires the "PositionChanged" event